# RTMP proxy to crop original video and send it to another RTMP server

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, reverse-proxy, rtmp, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to crop the video from an RTMP stream and send it to another RTMP server which always change. My understanding is that I should use `nginx-proxy` and `ffmpeg`, can anybody help me on how to set it up?

I suppose that i need to send the stream to an endpoint like `/stream/:stream-key/:next-server-ip` process the stream with ffmpeg and then send it to the :next-server-ip, what language should I use in the backend for this?

Comment: Why do you need `nginx`? Isn't it enough just to capture RTMP stream from source, crop it and put result into the target?

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov i could use node-media-server instead of nginx what I need is to be able to crop a RTMP signal coming from one service ( Opentok ) before it reaches Brightcove Live endpoint. This is something i need to be able to do programmatically for lots of streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 strategies for processing such task:

1. **"Pull"**

You have some published rtmp stream and use ffmpeg to pull it, convert and send result to another server:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://source-server/stream -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://next-server/stream
```

2. **"Push"**

RTMP stream is pushed to your server which processes it and sends result to another server. For such task you can use [nginx-rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) module for nginx and setup ffmpeg command using [exec_push](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#exec_push) directive:

```
application src {
    live on;
    exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/src/$name -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://next-server/stream 2>>/var/log/ffmpeg-$name.log;
}
```

When someone start to stream to `rtmp://your-server/src/stream_name` this `ffmpeg` command will be executed and the processing will begin

For additional information about video cropping and related `ffmpeg` parameters see https://video.stackexchange.com/a/4571

Comment: What would be the better way to do that ,#1 or #2 ? I have to do something like that. I have to stream a live event but now I have so much viewers and I wanna add more servers so I have 3 servers for doing streamer, it is not ?